# How to generate sha512 hash with a salt using command line?

Tags: java, linux

I use the below Java snippet to generate a hash password using an input and salt. Is there a way I can get that in Linux command line?

```
public String getPwd(String input, String salt) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    md.update(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    byte[] pwd= md.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(pwd));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sha512sum`.

`cat salt.dat myfile.dat | sha512sum -b`

Seems the `-b` is required for binary input (defaults to text, which can potentially result in different checksums depending on the encoding).

Comment: Does that myfile.dat contain my first input?

Comment: @Guru if you're looking to get the same result as from your Java code (except the Base64 part), then yes. It needs to be your input in UTF-8.

Comment: I am not getting the result same as the Java code. Yes, my input is a normal string. Not sure what am I doing wrong

Comment: There's no base64 encoding in the commandline, it provides the result as a hexstring. If you're just trying to verify your code, print out the [hexstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java).

Comment: @Guru just try `cat salt.dat myfile.dat | sha512sum -b | base64`

Comment: @SergeyVoytovich that'll base64 encode the hexstring and not the bytes, so it won't give the same result.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman .. i was hoping I will get result in command line along with base64 encoding..